# Rails 5 complex joins query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a join query that works:

The goal is to retrieve candidates not associated with campaigns with id in `id` (`Array`) through campaign_addings

```
Candidate.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN campaign_addings ON campaign_addings.candidate_id = candidates.id AND campaign_addings.campaign_id IN (#{id.join(',')})").where('campaign_addings.candidate_id IS NULL')
```

But well.. This query is really ugly, I would like to recreate this behavior with pure ActiveRecord DSL and no SQL, I have this for now:

```
Candidate.left_outer_joins(:campaign_addings).where(campaign_addings: { campaign_id: id, candidate_id: nil })
```

The good query generates:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "candidates" LEFT OUTER JOIN campaign_addings ON campaign_addings.candidate_id = candidates.id AND campaign_addings.campaign_id IN (4) WHERE (campaign_addings.candidate_id IS NULL)
```

And the bad one:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "candidates"."id") FROM "candidates" LEFT OUTER JOIN "campaign_addings" ON "campaign_addings"."candidate_id" = "candidates"."id" WHERE "campaign_addings"."campaign_id" = 4 AND "campaign_addings"."candidate_id" IS NULL
```

You can see this is really close, but I think I a missing something, can't find the way to join something like the first query.

Edit:

Plus, there is a SQL Injection vulnerability

Comment: Sometimes leaving it ugly but simple is a good solution. It will run faster. And anyone looking at your code can piece together what the query will be doing. Rather than guessing the AR one

Comment: I know right, but maybe there is a real good solution I am missing... a keyword, something..

Comment: what exactly is the problem? Have you tried doing it 2+ ids in the condition? Both versions should generate the same result

Comment: The second version does not work at all, this is my problem. It returns 0 results when the first returns 13 results